# Android getting SlidingMenu status?

Tags: android, toggle, slidingmenu

I used jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu library

I want to toggle the SlidingMenu after click a button

but I need to getting the SlidingMenu status is it toggled or not

so I want to achieve something like:

```
if(getSlidingMenu().isToggled()){
    toggle(); // to close the menu
}else{
    Log.e("test","menu not toggled");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isMenuShowing()`, Do you mean this?